# Redirect domain on subfolder to sub-sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website installed on the following folder structure:

mywebsite.com

-/test

--/current

My goal is to have a domain

> mywebsite.com/test

with RewriteCond to look into /current subfolder.

Here is what I have so far :

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^$ /test [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/current/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /current/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ current/index.php [L]
```

But unfortunately this createt redirection issue